# Export CSV using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, internet-explorer-10

I have a classic ASP application with a page that will export a CSV file. It works in all browsers except Internet Explorer (IE). It worked in IE before the company updated everyone's computer to Windows 8 and IE10. I've tried compatibility mode on and off and I have used F12 to change the Browser Mode and Document Mode. I have the following code to set headers and etc...

```
Response.ContentType = "application/csv"
Response.AddHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfilename.csv"
```

I've also tried Response.Content-Type="text/csv" with no success. I've been banging Google hard for a day or two looking for resolutions but cannot find any help. Does anyone have some suggestions?

EDIT: Below is some more information I've pulled from Fiddler about the headers. Also, I should have mentioned that Fiddler shows the data is being written to the Response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,private
Content-Type: text/csv
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=somefilename.csv
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 14 Aug 2014 17:41:56 GMT
Connection: close
```

**UPDATE:**
I've been able to determine the issue is occurring due to the fact I am uploading a file and then trying to export file in the same Request/Response cycle. When I submit the data manually (via hidden fields) and not upload the file, the download works. So now I am trying to figure out a fix for this situation.

Comment: Can you describe the issues symptoms, does it download?, Is corrupted when it downloads?, do you get an error? At the moment you've give us nothing to go off.

Comment: There are no errors being thrown or displayed. IE freezes and is unresponsive. I have to use Task Manager to kill IE. In debugging the issue it seems that it freezes when it tries to add the "Content-Disposition" header. Fiddler shows the data being written to the response but it seems as though IE is not understanding the headers.

Comment: Sounds like it's not your csv but the OS struggling with associating the file type, do you get the same behaviour on other machines? Try changing the `Response.ContentType` to `text/plain` and changing the filename to `somefilename.txt`, does it download now? If so it's a file association problem with the `csv` filetype.

Comment: can you please share the working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

It turns out to be an Internet Explore plus Windows Update issue. See the link below for more information.

[Problem Description](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/771e3435-1345-41cf-8682-d88abd5140a1/ie-10-and-11-freeze-after-kb2962872-web-application-with-file-uploaddownload?forum=ieitprocurrentver)